# LINQ To SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains operator

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Consider this LINQ To SQL query. It's intention is to take a string[] of search terms and apply the terms to a bunch of different fields on the SQL table:

```
string[] searchTerms = new string[] {"hello","world","foo"};
List<Cust> = db.Custs.Where(c => 
   searchTerms.Any(st => st.Equals(c.Email))
|| searchTerms.Any(st => st.Equals(c.FirstName))
|| searchTerms.Any(st => st.Equals(c.LastName))
|| searchTerms.Any(st => st.Equals(c.City))
|| searchTerms.Any(st => st.Equals(c.Postal))
|| searchTerms.Any(st => st.Equals(c.Phone))
|| searchTerms.Any(st => c.AddressLine1.Contains(st))
)
.ToList();
```

An exception is raised:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator

**Question:**
Why is this exception raised, and how can the query be rewritten to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Replace the usages of Any with Contains in your query. eg:

```
searchTerms.Contains(c.Email)
```

This should get the result you're looking for. It looks backwards, but it's correct- it'll generate an IN operator for each field inside a Contains with all the elements in searchTerms.

The AddressLine1 part won't work this way- you'll have to loop-generate the comparisons yourself with

```
c.addressLine1.Contains(...)
```

Something like [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) can be helpful for this.

Comment: @nitzmahone: thanks, will check out PredicateBuilder, it looks promising!

Comment: I would be concerned that the awesomeness of `PredicateBuilder` will disappoint in a LinqToSql implementation as some of the conditions may not be implemented by the LinqToSql provider (the exact problem you describe in your question).

Comment: +1 for the `.Contains()` - generally a good replacement for equations that are not supported by LinqToSql. Caution is advised with `PredicateBuilder` even being an option.

Comment: I use PredicateBuilder all the time, almost exclusively with Linq to SQL. Huge time saver and pretty much the only way to do OR'd dynamic searches like this when the column list is variable (ie, "advanced search").

Answer (score 11):

Just a thought (not directly related to the question, but it might help other viewers):

I was getting the same error message as you, even though I was using the Contains() method correctly, and it took me quite a while to figure out that the root of my problem was returning an IEnumerable to something that needed to further filter the results of the L2S query. Once I changed the function's return type to an IQueryable, the problem went away. It makes sense, seeing that an IEnumerable can't be further filtered, but an IQueryable can.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but none of the solutions posted above worked for me.

What worked for me was to cast `db.Custs` into a list **first**, as so:

```
List<Cust> =db.Custs.ToList<Cust>.Where(...
```

I have no idea why it worked, but it did.

Comment: It works in your case because you've bypassed the database and are working against the collection, rather than having the `Contains()` extension method be translated into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the error is saying that you are doing a join between two collections, one of which is a database table, and the other is an array.  LINQ isn't designed to handle that -- either both need to be in the database, or both in-memory (with a special case exception made when using `Contains`)