# LINQ contains one match from array of strings

Tags: c#, string, linq, linq-to-sql, search

Having trouble getting this to work:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve search suggestions from previous searches
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] getSearchSuggestions(int SectionID, string Query)
    {
        string[] Suggestions;
        string[] Words = Query.Split(' ');

        using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
        {
            Suggestions = (from c in db.tblSearches
                        where c.SectionID == SectionID &&
                        Words.Any(w => c.Term.Contains(w))
                        select c.Term).ToArray();
        }

        return Suggestions;
    }
```

I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

I want to return records where the field `c.Term` contains any of the words in the `Words` array.  I would also like to have it ordered by the total number of matches, but that seems really hard to do!  I found [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546166.aspx). But I can't get it to work with my query either.  Also [found this but it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757214/linq-entity-string-field-contains-any-of-an-array-of-strings).

Comment: This syntax looks good to me. I ported it to some local code and was able to make an identical query work against one my own contexts. (using 3.5 framework)

Comment: @Joel I'm on the 4 framework and this throws the error quoted :(

Comment: Is c.term just a simple string value?

Comment: @esas yes it is, nvarchar(60)

Comment: Is it going to be a string with more than one word in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after plugging away enough at it I realized that the problem wasn't the Any or the Contains. Linq to SQL doesn't like you combining the local sequence (words) with the SQL collection (db.tblSearches). So in order to accomplish this, you have to break it out into 2 separate queries.

```
public static string[] getSearchSuggestions(int SectionID, string Query)
{
    string[] Suggestions;
    string[] Words = Query.Split(' ');

    using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
    {
        string[] all = (from c in db.tblSearches
                    where c.SectionID == SectionID
                    select c.Term).ToArray();

        Suggestions = (from a in all
                       from w in Words
                       where a.Contains(w)
                       select a).Distinct().ToArray();


    }

    return Suggestions;
}
```

Keep in mind, that in the second query, the `Contains` is case sensitive, so you might have to add a case-insensitive extension method or go old school and kick them `.ToUpper()`. I ran this in 4.0 on one of my contexts and it returned all 88 strings correctly (out of a possible 9814). Though it was a thorough PITA. Definite +1 on this question.

**Edit:**
Added `.Distinct()` to the final answer.

Comment: Thanks a million! :D That's awesome, works a charm, except it sometimes returns duplicates but I think I can fix that.  Also `where a.ToLower().Contains(w.ToLower())` seems to make it case insensitive as well.

Comment: `select a).Distinct().ToArray();` for distinct, combined with lowercase is perfect answer :D thanks a million!

Comment: @Tom Gullen: You could probably throw in a .Distinct() call before the .ToArray() call to get rid of any dupes.

Comment: @Joel, Dosen't really make sense to do `.ToArray()` after the `all` variable - Why not let it remain lazy, until it's needed? With your current code example, it will both iterate through the elements at `.ToArray()`, and then again in the `Suggestions`.

Comment: @ebb: Nevermind my last comment, I misread yours. You probably could avoid the first `.ToArray()` and gain a bit of performance at it as well. When I was doing my testing I was trying to keep the types compatible to eliminate that as being a possible problem.

Answer (score 3):

First convert your array to a list,

```
 List<string> wordList = Words.ToList();
```

then change your linq query as follows:

```
    Suggestions = (from c in db.tblSearches                           
where c.SectionID == SectionID &&                           
Words.Contains(c.Term)                           
select c.Term).ToArray();
```

I think I see your problem though. In your original query you are using c.Term.Contains()...  Contains is an extension method that needs to be called on an object that implements Enumerable so you cannot call it on a field you are getting back from your database call.  That is why the other user that answered your question said you needed to flip things around in your Contains, because it is never going to let you make that call on c.Terms.

Comment: Doesn't work, I changed Words to wordList as well.  .Contains is not the same as .Any, I need it to match records where it finds 1 or more matches, contains doesn't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to flip your order of the Contains clause:

```
        Suggestions = (from c in db.tblSearches 
                    where c.SectionID == SectionID && 
                    Words.Contains(w => c.Term) 
                    select c.Term).ToArray();
```

Comment: This returns no results with test data?  It's what I tried first.  It needs to find results where c.Term contains 1 or more matches in Words

Comment: I'm going on this question by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757214/linq-entity-string-field-contains-any-of-an-array-of-strings

Comment: Anyways you have to replace the Any for Contains. [Take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementatio).

Comment: This answer definitely won't work - it's **not** the same to say a word occurs in a term than at least one word occurs within a term. Consider words = { brown, fox }, term = 'the brown fox'

Comment: Ok. From your original question, the above would solve the error you were getting, but it doesn't return the results that you were wanting. It sounds like you wanted where term in your tblSearches contains any/all of the words in your array. If you are doing all (And) see [link](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/Dynamically-extending-LINQ-queryies-without-building-expression-trees.aspx). Doing or is a bit more challenging. FWIW, it is possible in LINQ 2 SQL to join an object array with an entityset, but you can't join a entityset with an array.