# Does LINQ convert code to SQL queries

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm a newbie to both the Entity Framework (EF) and LINQ.

My question's a little lengthy but really very simple. If I create a query to retrieve data from my RDBMS using LINQ, say:

```
using (MyEntities myEntities = new MyEntities())
{
    // ...
    var query = from rec in myEntities.SomeTable
                where rec.Id == someId
                select rec;
    // ...
}
```

When ultimately executed, is this actually converted to SQL and executed on the DB itself (wherever that machine is), or are the underlying records actually retrieved onto the host machine first and then filtered by the running app itself (using some LINQ and/or EF magic).

IOW, would all records in "SomeTable" above be retrieved onto the host machine from the underlying DB and then LINQ and/or EF takes care of locating the record(s) with the given "someId", or is the above query converted to an actual SQL statement and executed on the DB machine itself (which then returns the given records).

I would assume it's the latter (it would be grossly inefficient otherwise) but can someone confirm this. Moreover, does this apply no matter how complicated the LINQ query is (since it may contain complicated joins, etc.), but not including any local functions that may be called in the query of course.

I'm just trying to understand conceptually what's going on under the hood, and whether LINQ can effectively be used as a high-level replacement for traditional SQL text queries (i.e., LINQ creates the actual SQL queries behind the scenes and sends them off to the DB for execution, but doesn't participate in the actual execution itself, other than handling local function calls in the query, if any). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is an SQL query generated in the background. It may be as complex as required to only fetch the relevant data.

If a query cannot be generated because certain LINQ features are not supported against a database, then the whole expression will not be compiled (to sql). You can override this behaviour manually if you want to fetch all data and then filter in a complex way on the client side. To do that, you place `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at some early point of your LINQ query, and carry on `where`'ing that list.

You can also [view the resulting SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882652).

More reading: [LINQ to SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399413).

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification. If something isn't supported by the underlying data source (DB in this case), are you saying the program won't even compile, or will an exception occur at runtime (presumably the former). Thanks.

Comment: @JohnBrown I meant "compiled to sql," as the expression will be valid from the compiler point of view, but unsupported in terms of linq2sql provider. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementati for an example.