# Using linq to perform text-based search when number of search words can be variable

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ To SQL exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementati)

I am trying the following query:

```
var data = (from bk in DataContext.Book
             where ((searchArray.Count() == 0 || searchArray.ToList().Any(x => bk.Name.Contains(x))) ||
                       (searchArray.Count() == 0 || searchArray.ToList().Any(x => bk.Genre.Contains(x)))))
```

where searchArray is a Array containing the individual words that I want to search for, I split the string the user entered and put the results in this array.  Whenever I try to run this I get the following error:
"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what is the correct way to perform this search?

In a nutshell, I am trying to allow a user to enter a string like "Hello World" and for a query to be generated that will look for either hello or world or both.  But, a user can enter any number of words.

Comment: _bk.Name.Contains_? _bk.Name_ is of type _IEnumerable<string>_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to build the lambda expression by hand:

```
static class ContainsAny
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo StringContains 
       = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    public static Builder<T> Words<T>(IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        return new Builder<T>(words);
    }    

    public static Builder<T> Words<T>(params string[] words)
    {
        return new Builder<T>(words);
    }    

    public sealed class Builder<T>
    {
        private static readonly ParameterExpression Parameter 
           = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");

        private readonly List<Expression> _properties = new List<Expression>();
        private readonly List<ConstantExpression> _words;

        internal Builder(IEnumerable<string> words)
        {
            _words = words
                .Where(word => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                .Select(word => Expression.Constant(word))
                .ToList();
        }

        public Builder<T> WithProperty(Expression<Func<T, string>> property)
        {
            if (_words.Count != 0)
            {
                _properties.Add(ReplacementVisitor.Transform(
                    property, property.Parameters[0], Parameter));
            }

            return this;
        }

        private Expression BuildProperty(Expression prop)
        {
            return _words
              .Select(w => (Expression)Expression.Call(prop, StringContains, w))
              .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
        }

        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Build()
        {
            if (_words.Count == 0) return (T obj) => true;

            var body = _properties
                .Select(BuildProperty)
                .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, Parameter);
        }
    }

    private sealed class ReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private ICollection<ParameterExpression> Parameters { get; set; }
        private Expression Find { get; set; }
        private Expression Replace { get; set; }

        public static Expression Transform(
            LambdaExpression source, 
            Expression find, 
            Expression replace)
        {
            var visitor = new ReplacementVisitor
            {
                Parameters = source.Parameters,
                Find = find,
                Replace = replace,
            };

            return visitor.Visit(source.Body);
        }

        private Expression ReplaceNode(Expression node)
        {
            return (node == Find) ? Replace : node;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
        {
            return ReplaceNode(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            var result = ReplaceNode(node);
            if (result == node) result = base.VisitBinary(node);
            return result;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (Parameters.Contains(node)) return ReplaceNode(node);
            return Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == node.Name) ?? node;
        }
    }
}
```

With this code in place, you can call:

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> filter = ContainsAny
    .Words<Book>(searchArray)
    .WithProperty(book => book.Name)
    .WithProperty(book => book.Genre)
    .Build();

var data = DataContext.Book.Where(filter);
```

For example, if the `searchArray` contains `{ "Hello", "World" }`, the generated lambda will be:

```
obj => (obj.Name.Contains("Hello") || obj.Name.Contains("World")) 
   || (obj.Genre.Contains("Hello") || obj.Genre.Contains("World")))
```

Comment: In terms of the from .. where linq query I have above, let's say I wanted to add a new search BookTypeID == bookTypeId, this would be coming from a dropdown a user selects among the other search criteria.  How would I add this to the where criteria?

Comment: @user1790300: Since you want to match both filters, you can simply call `Where` multiple times: `Data.Book.Where(wordFilter).Where(book => book.BookTypeID == bookTypeId)`

Comment: I am looking for ExpressionVisitor, which library is it in?

Comment: @user1790300: It's a [.NET 4.0 class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace of the `System.Core` assembly. If you're using .NET 3.5, there's an [implementation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which you can use instead.

Comment: For the bookType example above, would that result in any performance hits or would linq perform one query instead of two.  Also, Thanks.  I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1790300: It would just be one query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you should be able to condense your query down to:

```
from bk in DataContext.Book
where searchArray.Contains(bk.Name) || searchArray.Contains(bk.Genre)
select bk
```

This is basically equivalent to the SQL:

```
select bk.*
from Book bk
where bk.Name in (...) or bk.Genre in (...)
```

Comment: You have missed `searchArray.Count() == 0` condition.

Comment: Would that work if Name contained the string "The Great Gatsby" and searchArray contained the strings {"The", "Great", "Gatsby"}?

Comment: @user1790300: No, it would perform exact text matches only. I missed that you were looking for partial matches as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you must combine interpreted and local queries which can hurt performance or use SQL CLR integration by creating CLR function on database.