# What Is the Difference Between These Two Queries Where One Throws System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I was experiencing an exception which searches well on this site:

> System.NotSupportedExceptionLocal sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementati) answer helpful.  However, seemingly contradicting the answer, this query works just fine for me:

```
return clients.Where(client => 
    client.CompanyID.HasValue && 
    client.Company.CompanyAssociations.Any(ass => 
       localListOfSearchStrings.Any(str => ass.Contact.FullName.Contains(str))));
```

Whereas this query, which to my eye looks exactly the same, throws the exception:

```
return stores.Where(store => 
    store.Asset.AssetOwners.Any(assetOwner => 
        assetOwner.Client.CompanyID.HasValue && 
        assetOwner.Client.Company.CompanyAssociations.Any(ass =>
            localListOfSearchStrings.Any(str => 
                ass.Contact.FullName.Contains(str)))));
```

I do not want to pull the list of records into local memory to evaluate.

Another complication is that the `localListOfSearchStrings` may contain first name or last names.

So I really need the evaluation to be

```
localListOfSearchStrings.Any(str => 
    CompanyAssociation.Contact.FullName.Contains(str))
```

and not, e.g.,

```
listOfLocalSearchStrings.Contains(CompanyAssociation.Contact.FullName)
```

Comment: Seeing the exception message it is surprising that the first query runs fine. Looks like you need a solution in which you build an "OR" query, e.g. with PredicateBuilder. Or move to Entity Framework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer was silly, of course.

The answer [cited above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementati) was correct.  The reason the query was working was because `clients` was actually casted to a list before the query was called - SQL Server Profiler alerted me to this fact.  Which was just awful.

A solution to the problem was, as Gert Arnold indicated above, to use PredicateBuilder (also suggested in the cited question).